# tracking position accuratly with gps in Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm following this to sign the current position of the user on a map, like a navigator
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Tracking_Position_and_Heading, and it works, but the position on the map isn't totally correct, the position is too approximate, sometime when i'm walking it signs me on another street or in the middle of a building. moreover, the position change after 5/10 seconds, that is too much time.

I also tried my app when driving car, totally doesn't work.

I have found similar issue and i tried similar solutions, https://archive.appcelerator.com/topic/3637/continually-monitor-gps-position-every-sec-best-accuracy-and-provider/1?page=1 : hope for some help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the accuracy of the location monitoring for both iOS and Android. An example from an app of mine:

```
  if (!Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
    throw new Error('Location Services Disabled');
  }

  if (OS_IOS) {
    Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Ti.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
    Ti.Geolocation.distanceFilter = Alloy.CFG.minUpdateDistance;
    Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS;
  }

  if (OS_ANDROID) {
    Ti.Geolocation.Android.addLocationProvider(Ti.Geolocation.Android.createLocationProvider({
      name: Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS,
      minUpdateDistance: Alloy.CFG.minUpdateDistance,
      minUpdateTime: (Alloy.CFG.minAge / 1000)
    }));
    Ti.Geolocation.Android.addLocationRule(Ti.Geolocation.Android.createLocationRule({
      provider: Ti.Geolocation.PROVIDER_GPS,
      accuracy: Alloy.CFG.accuracy,
      maxAge: Alloy.CFG.maxAge,
      minAge: Alloy.CFG.minAge
    }));
    Ti.Geolocation.Android.manualMode = true;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Zandbergen, Your code is quite impressive, i even went through it on the git.

Couple of questions though on android.
1. What does the maxAge, and the minAge parameters signify. Not very clear from the documentation.
2. What is the use of minUpdateTime when minAge and maxAge parameters are there.
3. Can i add multiple location provider having there own rules? In case the GPS reception is less, and i still want the application to get tracked for latitude and longitude, this code doesn't work in case i am at a low reception of GPS. The location event never gets a hit in Android

Comment: maxAge: Controls the freshness of location updates. Do not forward an update unless it is newer than maxAge milliseconds.
 
What do you find not clear about the docs? minAge:  Controls the frequency of location updates. Do not forward an update unless at least minAge milliseconds have passed since the last good location update (that is, the last update from any provider that generated a location event).